# Add records into internal table

Tags: abap, internal-tables

I want to add records into an internal table. When I am trying to add, t is showing the error of

**The field "ITAB_EMPLOYEE" is unknown, but there is a field with the similar name "ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I". .**

```
    REPORT zitab_siddhi.

    TYPES: BEGIN OF EMPLOYEE,
             EMPID    TYPE C,
             EMPNAME     TYPE string,
             EMPADDRESS  TYPE c,
             EMPEMAIL    TYPE c,
             EMPDEPT     TYPE c,
             EMPROLE     TYPE string,
             EMPCONT TYPE C,
           END OF employee.

    TYPES ITAB_EMPLOYEE TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF EMPLOYEE.

    DATA: ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I TYPE EMPLOYEE.

      ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I-EMPID = '123'.
      ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I-EMPNAME = 'JOHN DOE'.
      ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I-EMPADDRESS = 'BANGALORE'.
      ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I-EMPEMAIL = 'JOHN@BANGALORE.COM'.
      ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I-EMPDEPT = 'SALES'.
      ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I-EMPROLE = 'MANAGER'.
      ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I-EMPCONT = '1234567890'.

 APPEND ITAB_EMPLOYEE_I TO ITAB_EMPLOYEE.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ITAB_EMPLOYEE` is declared as table type and not as internal table in your code. Replace `TYPES` with `DATA`:

```
DATA itab_employee TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF employee.
```